# is there any data binding techniques available in asp.net like in wpf binding mechanism

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, user-interface, binding

Is there any data binding mechanisms in asp.net web forms like in wpf ui binding through data context and binding elements,static resource and dynamic resources of business objects.

I am doing a project using asp.net web forms. for easier coding i am asking.

Answer (score -1):

Check out http://aspnetmvvm.codeplex.com/.

I recommend to use Asp.Net MVC technology. using HTML and javascript u have several frameworks like KnockoutJS or even better AngularJS.